# Facebook Approval Process for multiple platform

Tags: facebook

We have Live Facebook app which we would like to use for Android App, iOS App, and Website.

***For Website*** we require Login Permission *(email,public_profile,**publish_actions**,user_friends)* all these are approved for website.

***For Android and iOS platform***
But now we would like to use same app for login from Android App, iOS App.
on which we will require only default facebook permission ( email, public_profile, user_friends)*. Can anybody suggest that do I need to undergo new Review and submission for thease platform.

Please consider that **publish_actions** permission requrie only on web platform and not on android and iOS.

Answer (score 4):

Once you got permissions approved for one platform, they can be used on any platform. Approval is tied to the app, not any specific platform.

If you have the permissions you need for web approved already, and don’t need any additional permissions for iOS and Android – then you don’t need to undertake any additional steps.
Further review will only be necessary, when you request a new permission that you have not send in for review yet on any platform at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks ans looks to be helpful